# Integrating Prometheus IO with python-django application

Tags: python, django, prometheus

I am going to integrate Prometheus io with my Python Django application to keep track of performance metrics of different APIs. I am new to Prometheus. I have gone through the documentation about Prometheus and recent python client. I have set it up in my local, but cannot figure out about how to push the metrics from my application. So if anyone has any suggestion regarding that, I will be really grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Funnily enough, I'm doing the same thing :) Given the lack of a python2 client for push, i'm planning on using the python client found here: https://github.com/prometheus/client_python

However, I'm a little unsure what the implications are going to be for  collecting metrics from multiple running gunicorn workers.

In answer to your question though, a good place to start is to look at the client code there, and I'm at least going to start by adding an end point to my django app at say `/health-check` or `/prometheus` and have that be the place that prometheus asks for metrics from

Comment: https://github.com/prometheus/client_python/issues/30 covers gunicorn support. /metrics is the standard endpoint name.